# Can I safely hook up 2 AAA batteries to a switch and ethernet without harming my computer?

Tags: batteries, ethernet, toggle-switch

I want to make an ethernet kill switch. I plan on taking 2 keystone jacks and wiring them to each other. Then putting a rocker switch between the orange wire to kill internet. How ever I have a rocker switch with an LED that I would love to have lit when internet is on. It has 3 prongs: POWER  |  ACC  |  GROUND.  I know how I would wire this if I was using it for something that how power going to it, but what I would love to do is use it for this internet kill switch and then hook up 2 AAA batteries to it as well. So I am wondering if there should be an concern for the computer or ethernet switch from the 2 AAA batteries. I plan to run the ORANGE wire to the ACC and GROUND prongs. Then I would also have to hook up the 2 AAA batteries to the POWER and GROUND prongs. Does that sound correct and safe for the hardware?

I am a complete noob when it comes to electrical so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: No. An Ethernet signal would not appreciate a 3V DC power connection on either side of one of the wires.

Comment: @Passerby The 3V circuit would only be connected at one point to the Ethernet circuit, so it shouldn't affect it.

Comment: However, note that high-speed data signals tend to be quite sensitive to things like geometry - it's possible that just putting the rocker switch in the data line will break it (or slow it down).

Comment: Yes, the Impedance of the differential pair is important. At minimum a dpst for both wires of a pair is needed to minimize any interference. But a physical switch is not to spec.

Comment: A so-called 'managed switch' is a common Ethernet component that can disconnect a network connection and reconnect it reliably.   Mechanical switching is noncompliant with 1000baseT and other wiring standards.

Comment: You can probably put an electronic switch in there: 
http://www.ti.com/product/SN74CBTLV3245A

Comment: If you think of a schematic, draw it instead of describing it verbally.

Answer (score 1):

Don't interfere with the signal wiring. You might get it to work or it may cause intermittent problems.

Instead use the switch to cut power to a hub or router. This has the advantage that you can use the hub power supply to light the LED and then be battery free.

If the indicator is a plain LED then you need to add a current limiting resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNEKyP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. How to wire up for a 12 V supply.*

There may already be a resistor in the switch but you have not supplied a part number or link to a datasheet so we can't check.